# MySQL Regexp, ignore letters inside parentheses

Tags: mysql, regex

I need to check whether a string contains all caps. However, it should ignore anything inside parentheses. Any non-letters are OK, too.

These should give true:

```
select binary  "ALL CAPS"         regexp "the expr"  from dual;
select binary  "CAPS (in paren)"  regexp "the expr"  from dual;
select binary  "ALL 1:,? CAPS "   regexp "the expr"  from dual;
```

This should give false:

```
select binary  "Not All CAps"     regexp "the expr"  from dual;
```

I thought about first doing a replace to remove anything in parentheses, but there doesn't seem to be a way to do a replace with regular expressions.

Comment: How should the solution treat nested or unmatched parentheses? E.g. CAPS (bla(bla) or even worse CAPS(bla   ?

Comment: These are unlikely to happen so it does not matter so much. Whatever is easiest, I think.

Comment: is it possible to have 2 or more parentheses?

Answer (score 0):

This allows anything inside a parenthesis pair, caps only outside.

```
^[^a-z]*(\(.*\))?[^a-z]*$
```

EDIT: some asterisks were missing.

Comment: Second and third expressions give False with this.

Comment: Should be like this: ^[^a-z]*(\(.*\))?[^a-z]*$